# how to create multiple payments using PHP SDK Quickbooks

Tags: php, sdk, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am creating App for Quickbook in PHP

I am using https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/

I want to make payments to multiple invoice in single API call.
I see their example but those make single payment. I need multiple payments towards various invoice for different customers.

How that is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution for me.

API have Batch Option to add multiple Objects in single Batch.

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

Their example code is here:

- https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-CRUD-PHP/blob/master/CRUD_Examples/Payment/PaymentCreate.php

So here's a snippet:

```
$theResourceObj = Payment::create([
  "CustomerRef" =>
  [
      "value" => "1"
  ],
  "TotalAmt" => 100.00,
  "Line" => [
  [
      "Amount" => 100.00,
      "LinkedTxn" => [
      [
          "TxnId" => "210",
          "TxnType" => "Invoice"
      ]]
  ]]
]);
$resultingObj = $dataService->Add($theResourceObj);
```

Then if you refer to their documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/payment#the-payment-object

You can see that the `Line` element is composed of `Zero or more transactions accounting for this payment.` including `The invoice to which payment is applied`. i.e. you can repeat things within `Line`, to apply the payment to more than one invoice.

So applying a payment to more than one invoice lists each individual invoice, and the amount of the payment to apply, in the repeating `Line` node array:

```
$theResourceObj = Payment::create([
  "CustomerRef" =>
  [
      "value" => "1"
  ],
  "TotalAmt" => 100.00,
  "Line" => [
    [
        "Amount" => 50.00,
        "LinkedTxn" => [
        [
            "TxnId" => "210",
            "TxnType" => "Invoice"
        ]]
    ],
    [
        "Amount" => 25.00,
        "LinkedTxn" => [
        [
            "TxnId" => "211",
            "TxnType" => "Invoice"
        ]]
    ],
    [
        "Amount" => 25.00,
        "LinkedTxn" => [
        [
            "TxnId" => "212",
            "TxnType" => "Invoice"
        ]]
    ],
  ]
]);
$resultingObj = $dataService->Add($theResourceObj);
```

Comment: This is perfect but this only solution when I have set of invoices for same customer. I am looking for solution where I want to post for multiple invoices but those belongs to different customers.

Comment: QuickBooks itself _does not support_ having a _single_ payment, against _invoices for more than one customer_. 

If you have multiple customers, then you need to create _multiple payments_. e.g. make more than one API call via `$dataService->add(...);`

You can bundle up those multiple API calls into a single HTTP request using the bulk/batch endpoints if you'd like. Examples are here:
https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/blob/master/src/_Samples/BatchQueries.php#L26